# Why can't I bind this onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, web-applications, onclick

I'm producing buttons for editing and removing each element in a `Firebase` database dynamically with `javascript`. And when there is only one element in the database (these elements represent polls/elections), the below code works fine. But when there is more than one database element, and hence more than one row of buttons, only the final pair of edit/remove buttons added are actually bound with the click event, which I suppose means all previous bindings are being overwritten in some way? I should also mention that both `pollsRef.once()` and `pollsSnapshot.forEach()` are asynchronous function calls (as are all `Firebase` API calls). Here is the function which creates and binds the buttons. ...

```
function displayCurrentPollsForEditing(pollsRef)
{
    var tbl = createTable();
    var th = ('<th>Polls</th>');
    $(th).attr('colspan', '3');
    $(th).appendTo($(tbl).children('thead'));
    pollsRef.once('value', function(pollsSnapshot) {
        pollsSnapshot.forEach(function(pollsChild) {
            var type = pollsChild.name();
            // If this is true if means we have a poll node
            if ($.trim(type) !== "NumPolls") 
            {
                // Create variables
                var pollRef = pollsRef.child(type);
                var pollName = pollsChild.val().Name;
                var btnEditPoll = $('<button>EDIT</button>');
                var btnRemovePoll = $('<button>REMOVE</button>');
                var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
                var voterColumn = $('<td></td>');
                var editColumn = $('<td></td>');
                var rmvColumn = $('<td></td>');
                // Append text and set attributes and listeners
                $(voterColumn).text(pollName);
                $(voterColumn).attr('width', '300px');
                $(btnEditPoll).attr({
                    'class': 'formee-table-button',
                    'font-size': '1.0em'
                });
                $(btnRemovePoll).attr({
                    'class': 'formee-table-remove-button',
                    'font-size': '1.0em'
                });
                $(btnEditPoll).appendTo($(editColumn));
                $(btnRemovePoll).appendTo($(rmvColumn));
                // Append to row and row to table body
                $(tr).append(voterColumn).append(editColumn).append(rmvColumn);
                $(tr).appendTo($(tbl).children('tbody'));
                // Append table to div to be displayed
                $('div#divEditPoll fieldset#selectPoll div#appendPolls').empty();
                $(tbl).appendTo('div#divEditPoll fieldset#selectPoll div#appendPolls');
                $(btnEditPoll).click(function() {
                    displayPollEditOptions(pollRef);
                    return false;
                });
                $(btnRemovePoll).click(function() {
                    deletePoll($(this), pollsRef);
                    return false;
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The buttons are just rendered in a programmatically generated table, all the `jQuery` selectors are correct.

Comment: You know, you're double wrapping all your selectors... I'm not sure if it still references the cached element if you do that, so after you `append` you're attaching the click event to another new element.

Comment: Could you clarify for me please? Thanks.

Comment: I just tested it here http://jsbin.com/unudij/1/edit and it seems to work fine, so the problem must be somewhere else. I'd still recommended you don't wrap elements twice. So you can just do `tr.text()` instead of `$(tr).text()` because `tr` is already a jQuery object.

Comment: Removing the double wraps didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure that example really recreates my problem, because I kinda think the issue is that these event assignments are happening within an asynchronous firebase call. But I'm not really familiar enough with this stuff to know how to fix it.